# EXTJS Grid rendering issue

Tags: html, extjs4

I am new to ExtJs and I am using ExtJs grid to show data in tabular format.
I am having following `<div>` structure -

```
<div id="div1" style="height:98%;padding:2px;display:none;">
     <div id="grid_id">
     </div>
</div>
```

The div1 contains the grid_div. Initially when the page loads the div1 display is set to none.
As its display is set to none, the extjs grid that is getting rendered to the div grid_div is not getting displayed.
If am setting the display as '' for the div1 then I am able to see the grid.

I am not unable to figure out what is causing the probelm, may be it's because while rendering the grid is taking the parent div's width and height, and as parents display is set to none its taking width and height as 0. But I am not sure about this.

Can somebody help me out to understand how the grid is rendered in this case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extjs is nothing more than *html/css* generated with *js*. So if you put `Ext.grid.panel` in div which parent has display:none, no grid will be displayed! You can see extjs structure simply by using firebug, cheers!